# How to show Images with source as the file path stored in Database

Tags: sql, react-native

I saved an image in a SQLite database in the smartphone as TEXT with the name **Path**.
I tried saving it in to ways:

- require('../assets/icon.png')
- '../assets/icon.png'

For the first method, when calling it on an Image component I use it like this:

```
<Image source={item.Path} />
```

Its value is for example 10.0 when using console.log to visualize it.
And I get the following error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.
```

But after adding another image, to the database, all the images will load. It doesn't work only when I start the app.

For the second method:

```
<Image source={require(`${item.Path}`)}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Invalid call at line 130: require("" + item.Path)
```

I have searched but can't find a optimal way to store an image path in the database and later use it in a Image component.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand here you're trying to use local path of your images from your database inside your react native project.  If I'm correct it can't work, you can't use local path of a distant directory, the api only serve the path not the file itself.

What I would do it's using amazon S3 bucket to upload static files, images in your case and you save the url of the uploaded images in your database. Then you call images in your code like this :

```
source={{ uri: "http://file.jpg" }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a 'solution'. In the local database I stored an int value called Path, and depending on the number stored. It would show specific images that were stored in the assets.